# Creating Directories with a Batch file

Tags: scripting, batch

I am intested in creating a batch file that can read in a text file which has four variables: customer name, customer number, customer order, products orders. I am using:

```
FOR /F "delims=, tokens=1,2,3,4" %%f in (test.txt)do md g:\%%f\%%g\%%h\%%i
```

However, it does not seem to create the subdirectories correct.

Can any one help?

Comment: What output do you see if you replace the `md` with `echo md`?  Are there spaces in the file name?  Why not quote them path?

Answer (score 8):

I suspect you may have spaces in some of the parameters. Try this:

```
FOR /F "delims=, tokens=1,2,3,4" %%f in (test.txt) do md "g:\%%f\%%g\%%h\%%i"
```